# How can you use Lightroom and still sync images across multiple devices?

Tags: post-processing, software, workflow, macintosh

I have been using Apple Photos for some time and I use iCloud to get all my photos to all my devices. Whether I take them on my dSLR (which is usually the case) and sync them to my Mac or iPad, or whether I take them from my iPhone, iCloud combined with Apple Photos makes the whole process of managing and syncing my photos *super* simple.

**But**, I want more photo editing features than Apple's Photos app offers, and am considering Lightroom. However, I'm worried that it's going to be complicated to manage my photos across devices.  ***How do you manage your Lightroom library across multiple devices?***

I have an iPhone, an iPad, and a Mac with OSX. I take most of my photos with my dSLR, which I like to transfer either to my Mac or iPad (when I'm traveling). Sometimes I take photos on my iPhone as well. It's really important for me to have them in one place.

Comment: Please try and cut this down to one answerable question; Stack Exchange isn't a traditional discussion board, so we don't do things like "hearing what works well for others".

Comment: If you're moving beyond Apple's offerings, you're going to have to adopt a new workflow, period. Pick one (say, Lightroom, or Dark Table, etc.), and dive deep and learn as much as you can. But there's no substitution to just doing it, finding out what works for you, and what doesn't. If you have specific problems with your chosen tool, come back here and ask, and we'll do our best to answer.

Comment: We really prefer one question per question so you can get a real answer, not just opinions. Maybe refocus this about what has you "worried about the logistics of Lightroom" and concentrate on that? In the meantime, maybe go view [Julianne Kost's "Getting Started with Lightroom 5" series](https://tv.adobe.com/show/getting-started-with-adobe-photoshop-lightroom-5/) to get an idea of the Lr workflow--it's a little out of date for CC, but simpler and more straightforward than going through [her CC training series](https://blogs.adobe.com/jkost/lightroom-training-videos).]

Comment: Thank you all! I rewrote the question to make it more focused.

Comment: There may be more built-up solutions, but storing your lightroom library and the photos you edit in a cloud-syncing folder like Google Drive or Dropbox would get those photos onto all of your devices.

Comment: @steel, I'd recommend posting that as an answer. See [this meta post](http://meta.photo.stackexchange.com/questions/4655/short-answers-as-comments-please-resist-the-urge).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are iOS and Android mobile app versions of Lightroom that can sync with the desktop application.  You'll be out of Apple's iCloud ecosystem, and doing this via Adobe's creative cloud (CC) service, but Adobe has built in the function to sync between the desktop version of the software and the Lightroom mobile device apps [see [this link]](https://helpx.adobe.com/lightroom/how-to/sync-photos-lightroom-mobile.html) .  The syncs also go in two directions, so edits you make on mobile devices get back to the desktop "catalog" (e.g., Lightroom database).

Comment: @RivkiLocker Because this is SE, and not a messageboard, consider [accepting](http://photo.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer), or (when you get the rep) [upvoting](http://photo.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/vote-up) an answer instead of a thanks comment. Please, take [the tour](http://photo.stackexchange.com/tour) if you plan to stick around.